# How to fetch nested elements in Mongo/

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to fetch nested elements from Mongo Collection. I need data for sem-1 but I'm getting everything under a particular student id.

References:

Mongo DB structure https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNGS8.png and this is my code

```
exports.gtMarks = async (req, res) => {
  const { student_id, semister } = req.body;
    try {
    const AllMarks = await MarksCardList.findOne({
      student_id: student_id,
      "marksCard_list.semister": semister,
          });
    res.status(200).json(AllMarks);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      message: "Cant fetch marks form db",
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting "sem-1" data for a particular student, you will first have to find that student and then you will have to find **marksCard_list** for "sem-1". For getting data only for "sem-1", you need to unwind **marksCard_list** array and then apply match query for finding the required semester.
Follwing is the code for getting required output for student_id = "1" and semester = "sem-1"

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {
    $match: {
      "student_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$marksCard_list"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "marksCard_list.semester": "sem-1"
    },  
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "marksCard_list.marks": 1
    }
  }
)
```

Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9oS7ahwAd1z) example from mongoplayground